# How can I add a Bonjour printer manually or via a different protocol in OSX?

Tags: macos, networking, wireless-networking, network-printer, osx-mavericks

There are 6 macs on my home network, 2 of them on Mavericks. The 10.9 macs cannot see my cannon MG5200 that is connected to the router via WiFi but the others can. I experienced this problem with my girlfriend's computer (10.8) once before but I was able to resolve the issue by resetting the printing system in system preferences. Unfortunately that does not appear to work with 10.9 as I've reset the printing system numerous time, with and without reboot, but system prefs fails to pick it up.

There's obviously an bug/incompatiblity with 10.9 that I'll have to wait to be fixes. Until then how can I use this printer via the network? Obviously windows computers can interface with it without Bonjour.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually add printers by going to Printers & Scanners preference pane, clicking **+** → **Add Printer or Scanner…** to add a printer, then select the IP tab. You can then manually enter the IP address of the printer to connect to it.

[image]